# Pegar o menor e maior valor de uma categoria com a contagem e ID

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, mariadb

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer um `SELECT` que me retorne o maior e menor valor de uma categoria  com seus respectivos `IDs` e a quantidade de cada categoria. O Algoritmo é complexo,porque precisa retornar em um única linha o resultado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tenho essa tabela:

```
ID | CAT | VALOR


1  |  A  | 153

2  |  B  | 100

3  |  A  | 26

4  |  A  | 65

5  |  B  | 23

6  |  A  | 161

7  |  B  | 150

8  |  A  | 30

9  |  C  | 50
```

E preciso deste retorno:

```
ID | CAT | QTDE_CAT | MENOR_VALOR | ID_MENOR_VALOR | MAIOR_VALOR | ID_MAIOR_VALOR

1  |  A  |    5     |   26        |      3         |    161      |      6

2  |  B  |    3     |    23       |      5         |    150      |      7

3  |  C  |    1     |    50       |      9         |    50       |      9
```

Comment: O que é este primeiro campo ID do resultado?

Comment: No caso de igualdade no menor ou no maior valor para diferentes ID o que deve ser listado?

Comment: O primento campo ID pode ser ignorado, é apenas uma sequencia. No caso de igualdade seria o exemplo da categiria C onde o maior e menor valor seriam iguais

Comment: Eu quis dizer para a mesma categoria existirem diferentes id com o mesmo menor e/ou maior valor.

Comment: Nao sei se entendi sua duvida, mas na realidade cada linha tem a quantidade de uma determinada categoria. Os IDs dessa tabela de entrada é unico e diferente para cada linha.Desta tabela de entrada, teria que fazer um resumo de saida mostrando uma linha para cada categoria com seus valores minimos e maximos e mostrando qual o ID destes vaalores minimos e maximos. tambem o total de cada categoria

Comment: eu fiz uma solução, acho que vai te servir, faça o teste!

Comment: Inacreditável. Muito obrigado, nem sei o que dizer. Funcionou perfeitamente de primeira. Muito obrigado mesmo. Você realmente conhece o assunto e é fora da curva seu conhecimento. Valeu mesmo!!!!

Comment: Edson assinale a resposta da sua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira coluna foi deixado de lado como dito no seu comentário que pode ser ignorado, então para ter o mesmo resultado da pergunta, tem que trabalhar com [SubConsulta](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15) para ter o **Id** do Valor **Menor** e **Maior**, *exemplo*:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(a.valor) QTDE_VALOR,
 MIN(a.valor) MENOR_VALOR, 
 MAX(a.valor) MAIOR_VALOR,           
 (SELECT b.ID FROM source b WHERE MIN(a.VALOR)=b.valor and a.CAT=b.CAT) ID_MENOR_VALOR, 
 (SELECT b.ID FROM source b WHERE MAX(a.VALOR)=b.valor and a.CAT=b.CAT) ID_MAIOR_VALOR,
 a.CAT
FROM source a
GROUP BY CAT
```

---

Resultado Online: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/899ba2/29)